# why is the sum over even and odd permutations the same?

Tags: matrices, determinant, symmetric-groups

let $m$ be an $n \times n$ matrix (over $\mathbb{R}$,say) and for a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ define the monomial:
$$
P_\sigma(M) = \prod_{j=1}^n m_{j,\sigma(j)}
$$
let $\tau$ be an odd permutation, and $A_n$ be the alternating subgroup of $S_n$. then the determinant of $M$ is given by:
$$
|M|= \sum_{\sigma \in A_n} P_\sigma -  \sum_{\sigma \in \tau A_n}P_\sigma
$$
if $M$ is singular we have
$$
\sum_{\sigma \in A_n} P_\sigma =  \sum_{\sigma \in \tau A_n}P_\sigma
$$

**question** is there any direct *intuitive* explanation of this fact?